# C Linker: Multiple Definitions

Tags: c, linker

I am writing a linked list implementation for a networking project I'm working on. It is split into two files: llist.h and llist.c. I include llist.h in several of the project files, and when compiling I link to library that I compiled which includes llist.c. Unfortunately I get a "multiple definitions" error for every method header in llist.h. ie:

```
../util//libdutil.a(llist.o): In function `LListContains':
llist.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `LListContains'
../util//libdutil.a(llist.o):llist.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

I'm not quite sure why I'm getting this error. It used to be fine, but this has started happening since I added one more method. Here is the entire h file:

```
#ifndef _LLIST_H_
#define _LLIST_H_

typedef struct _LinkedList
{
    int length;
    void* data;
    struct _LinkedList* head;
    struct _LinkedList* tail;
}* LinkedList;

LinkedList LListContains(LinkedList list, void* data, int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *));

void* getDataLList(LinkedList list);

LinkedList createLList(void* data);

void* getFromHeadLList(LinkedList list, int pos);

void* popHeadLList(LinkedList list);

void* popTailLList(LinkedList list);

LinkedList getNextLList(LinkedList current);

LinkedList getPrevLList(LinkedList current);

void addHeadLList(LinkedList list, void* data);

void addTailLList(LinkedList list, void* data);

void FreeLList(LinkedList list);

#endif
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: Okay, the problem seems to come from the following code snippet in one of the project files:

```
OPP_DIRECTION(getDirToXYPOS((XYPOS*)getFromHeadLList(memories[avID], 0), &curPos)))
```

Note that getFromHeadLList is the method that I added to llist.h and defined in llist.c. By simply commenting out that part and adding in a dummy parameter, ie:

```
OPP_DIRECTION(getDirToXYPOS(&curPos, &curPos)))
```

It compiles fine.

Comment: It would help if you show the commands that are being used for compiling and linking. And make sure you do not add `llist.c` into your IDE's project (as it's compiled as a separate library).

Comment: Technically, the error messages look like you have put `llist.c` twice into the static library but that doesn't make sense (however, try recompiling the library from scratch erasing the .a file). And to make sure you have no `llist.c` in your project try linking without `-ldutil` command switch. If it compiles, you have somehow included the llist.c in the project.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have compiled your `llist.c` into your project as well as into the static library.

Comment: That was the first thing I checked, and is not the case, unfortunately. The strange thing is that I haven't changed the makefile at all for the past 3 days and this issue just cropped up 20 minutes ago when I added in the "getFromHeadLList" method (which I define in the c file).

Comment: Do you use some kind of IDE? have you opened the .c file in the IDE to add the method? Does your IDE actually use your Makefile?

Comment: Nope, no IDE. The plot has thickened, though, I don't think it's an h file problem; it seems to come from calling one of the methods in one of the project files. I'm about to update the OP with the info, thanks for the help so far.